# Assign current WorkBook to Workbook object in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've tried to assign the current workbook to a workbook object:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

wb = ThisWorkbook
```

In this instance, the code is running in and is the currently active workbook.  But I get the following error, where am I going wrong:

`91 - Object variable or With block variable not set`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When assigning an object to a variable you have to use `Set`

```
Set wb =ThisWorkbook
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually knew that, it just totally disappeared into some dark corner.  Thanks for reminding me!